# AWS EFS error with ECS volume with nextcloud docker

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, nextcloud, amazon-efs

I am working on a nextcloud docker and I am connecting efs storage so that containers have common storage. I have two problems:-

1. Only one container runs the installation automatically and rest wait while installation is going on
2. I get permission denied with www-data:root even when i have 33:0 owner setting in efs access points

Please help! I can give more information if you require

Comment: Since I'm not into AWS, I can only supply a general warning: Multiple Nextcloud instances (or even non-nc containers) using the same filesystem will sooner or later lead to a database out-of-sync, problems with versioning, and DB sequences. Providing federated shares from one instance to others would do the trick. If external services have to access nc data, you should consider using WebDAV.

Answer (score 0):

1. Scaling in and out works fine for me if you have Redis connected and enabled within your Nextcloud Docker configuration. In combination with EFS as storage for backend files and S3 as primary data storage you should not have issues with scaling.
   But for installation and upgrading you have a downtime anyway. Therefore i would suggest to scale in to just one instance for maintenance (+ initially while installing), do the upgrade, wait for Nextcloud being available and then turning on autoscaling etc. again.
2. I set the EFS access point Creation Info to `33:0` and `0770`. With an initial installation of NextCloud this works. Tested multiple times. If you change that afterwards it does not work. Then you have to mount the EFS within an EC2 instance and set permissions manually.

Tested with Versions 19.x to 21.0.1